# My Stack Overflow reputation score is decreasing due to Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

I have asked a question on Meta Stack Overflow. The question was not up to standards according to Meta Stack Overflow policy, so due to the question my reputation became zero. But now my Stack Overflow reputation is also decreasing due to the question. I want to save my reputation score on Stack Overflow. What to do?

Comment: [Meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773) -- _"Increase of voting activities observed in main site posts that have been exposed at meta. Most ironic when someone complaining to Meta about "unfair downvotes" on another site gets more downvotes. Also seen: closing, re-opening, deleting etc. Often the opposite of the desired result for the user who came to Meta about the specific question..."_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you ask a question on Meta about why your questions are not being answered on SO, that will intrigue people to look at your questions on Stack Overflow. The reason they would look at your questions, is to find out why they are not being answered, and then possibly give you advice on what you might do to possibly receive more answers.

Since they have every right to upvote / downvote  and more to any question on Stack Overflow, they must have downvoted because they felt that was the appropriate thing to do.

I saw your other question on Meta, but I did not go and check out your SO account. However, I just did view your 3 questions on SO, and they all seem to be "give me teh codez" type questions. People on SO do not write code for you. They help people who are running into issues with code they've already written.

> I want to save my reputation score on stackoverflow please help me.

At this point, you will have to edit your questions substantially to make them upvote worthy. I'd advise you to take all the advice you got on the other meta question you started, before you ask any new questions.

Comment: Also known as _The Meta Effect_. Post about a question, answer, or user, and you'll draw attention to them - and votes will follow.

Answer (score 5):

Please consider these downvotes as *constructive criticism* and make more efforts when you ask/answer a  question on both Meta and Stack Overflow.

When you get many downvotes, it's an indication that something is wrong in your questions/answers and you should reconsider the way you're doing this.

As already told before, people are interested and curious about your questions when you've posted the question about your Stack Overflow reputation, so they visit your profile there to better understand what you're talking about.. but then.. they see your questions, and as a faithful users, they have to downvote.

I highly recommend you to go through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and really read it.